# React context updating with loop, but not for individual item

Tags: reactjs, react-context, rerender

I have a React Context and a reducer that updates the context like this:

```
case setAllExtras:
            for (let i=0; i < state.stuff['extras'].length; i++) {
                state.stuff['extras'][i][Object.keys(state.stuff['extras'][i])[0]]['include'] = true
            }
            return {...state}
```

This works and updating this property updates an array map of a component:

```
    {extras ? (
                        <div>
                            {context.state.customerInfo.couple === false ? (
                                context.state.retirementSpending.extras.map((item, index) => {
                                    let key = Object.keys(item);
                                    let opaque = item[key]['include'];
                                    return (
                                        <Bar
                                            opaque={opaque}
                                            addRemoveBarHandler={(add, barName) => {addRemoveBarHandler(add, barName)}}
                                        />
                                    );
                                })
                            ) : (
                                context.state.retirementSpending.extras.map((item, index) => {
                                    let key = Object.keys(item);
                                    let opaque = item[key]['include'];
                                    return (
                                        <AmmoniteBar
                                            opaque={opaque}
                                            addRemoveBarHandler={(add, barName) => {addRemoveBarHandler(add, barName)}}
                                        />
                                    );
                                })
                            )}
                       </div>) : ...
```

This works and the value of opaque is changed for every Bar component.

When I try to change the opaque value of a single Bar component, it does not update the DOM and the component is not rerendered.

This in the reducer changes the value in the context, but change is not reflected in the DOM:

```
case setBar:
            const key = action.payload.bar
            for (let i=0; i < state.stuff['extras'].length; i++) {
                if (state.stuff['extras'][i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log("KEY FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                    state.stuff['extras'][i][Object.keys(state.stuff['extras'][i])[0]]['include'] = true
                }
            }
            return {...state}
```

How do I get the mapped array to change?

Comment: I believe the issue your facing is one of mutability. It seems like you’re changing the values in the reducer by mutating the array. Even though you’re returning {...state} by spread syntax and creating a new object the state.stuff.extras is still the same array. This doesn’t play well with React. I suggest you make a deep copy of your state and then modify the copy and return it.